# How to use async functions within functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So lets say you have this sync function you call **a** and another async function **b** that you want to put within **a**. And so you would have something like this:

```js
async function b(){
      //some code here
}
function a(){
    

}
```

And now lets say we add some code into **a** and call **b**:

```js
async function b(){
      //some code here
}
function a(){
      b()
      //other code here
}
```

Now lets say you want to run the code within **a** only if **b** has returned its promise. Well if you have direct access to **b** then its all fine, just make it a sync function. That would work but what if *you didn't have access to **b***. Here comes the problem. If you specifically want to run it after **b** then you could use something like .then():

```js
async function b(){
     //some code here
}
function a(){
     b().then(<results for example>=>{
     //other code
     })
}
```

But what if **a** was an async function, how would that work? Could i use await or anything of that sort?

Comment: Pretty much the only reason to have async functions is to use `await` inside them. There is almost no benefit if you don't.

Comment: how would that work tho?

Comment: @VLAZ The other benefit is that exceptions and return values are converted into promises

Comment: @JuanMendes it's part of the "almost". It's a *very small* benefit. I'd say `await` is more than 90% of the reason to use async.

Comment: @DcraftBg `await b()`

Comment: Yes, if you have `async function a(){}`, you can do `const bReturn = await b(); console.log(bReturn)`

Comment: @DcraftBg — You should probably start out with the MDN documentation for language features you don't understand in order to get a basic understanding of them before resorting to SO.

Comment: @VLAZ I love the fact that I can write a function that returns a promise without needing to call `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()`. I would put it at 25%  It happens often when I do some caching.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a function async and await for b function, then b function will return data, otherwise it will return promise.

```js
async function b(){
    //some code here
}
async function a(){
    const data = await b();
    // Do something with data
}
```